# Unpaired but not paired ttest loop in R working

Tags: r, for-loop, t-test

I have a loop that goes through a dataframe, runs ttests and stores the resulting p-value of each ttest in another dataframe.

Here is the loop where 'mydata' is the dataframe that the ttests are being run on. 'mydata' is a dataframe with 4 columns:

```
df <- mydata
mydf <- data.frame(c(1:4))

# this is the new dataframe being initialized to store my p-values

row.names(mydf) <- names(df)
for(i in names(df)){
  if(sd(df[[i]]) == 0) {

  # this prevents the loop from terminating and returning an error when ttests 
  # are run on columns with binary values 

  } else {
    ttest <- t.test(df[df$Pre==1,][[i]], df[df$Pre==2,][[i]], paired=FALSE)

    # 'Pre' is the column that groups my data into 
    # distinct cohorts. I am comparing the Pre cohort versus the Post cohort 
    # in these ttests.  

    mydf[i,1] <- ttest$p.value
  }
}
mydf
```

Here is my output of mydf for an unpaired (paired=FALSE) ttest:

```
          c.1.4.                             
density 0.3569670
clust   0.9715987
Pre     3.0000000
HC      4.0000000
```

However, when I change paired=FALSE to paired=TRUE (to run a paired ttest), here is mydf:

```
           c.1.4.
density      1
clust        2
Pre          3
HC           4
```

I checked this line of my loop in isolation using the first column of my dataframe, '1' in double brackets,(for paired=TRUE) and it does appear to be outputting a p-value:

```
ttest <- t.test(df[df$Pre==1,][[1]], df[df$Pre==2,][[1]], paired=TRUE)
ttest$p.value
[1] 0.356967
```

Below is a sample dataset that you can use to reproduce the error:

```
            density      clust      Pre HC
RDHC008A_13 0.47991     0.676825    1   1
RDHC009A_13 0.49955     0.696441    1   1
RDHC010A_16 0.491454    0.706507    1   1
RDHC013A_13 0.442879    0.689118    1   1
RDHC014A_13 0.453823    0.691603    1   1
RDHC016A_16 0.481259    0.706978    1   1
RDHC019A_06 0.515442    0.699514    1   1
RDHC021A_15 0.449925    0.685202    1   1
RDHC022A_12 0.461319    0.705446    1   1
RDHC023A_11 0.468816    0.667698    1   1
RDHC024A_12 0.515142    0.719474    1   1
RDHC025A_13 0.496702    0.710877    1   1
RDHC026A_12 0.477061    0.695061    1   1
RDHC027A_12 0.515442    0.722269    1   1
RDHC029A_12 0.406747    0.669998    1   1
RDHC030A_12 0.476162    0.69219     1   1
RDHC032B_13 0.50075     0.685474    1   1
RDHC034B_07 0.525487    0.725558    1   1
RDHC036B_07 0.468816    0.698904    1   1
RDHC038B_07 0.470015    0.706668    1   1
RDHC039B_07 0.511544    0.712818    1   1
RDHC041A_14 0.551574    0.732983    1   1
RDHC004C_12 0.486207    0.695121    2   1
RDHC005C_12 0.505997    0.695598    2   1
RDHC006C_13 0.487406    0.697044    2   1
RDHC013C_12 0.41979     0.685518    2   1
RDHC015C_13 0.297751    0.69632     2   1
RDHC016C_16 0.463718    0.700011    2   1
RDHC019C_14 0.508096    0.690071    2   1
RDHC021C_12 0.448426    0.688265    2   1
RDHC022C_12 0.468816    0.700968    2   1
RDHC024C_12 0.515292    0.70664     2   1
RDHC025C_13 0.473163    0.704231    2   1
RDHC027C_12 0.518741    0.732939    2   1
RDHC030C_11 0.489205    0.708174    2   1
```

You can import it by doing the following:

copy the data and paste it within the quotation marks of the code below into R:

```
zz <- ""
```

now, assign the data to a data.frame:

```
mydata <- read.table(text=zz, header=TRUE)
```

I have no idea why changing the 'paired' parameter to TRUE would cause this to happen. Any help/advice would be much appreciated. Thanks - Paul

Comment: This seems very unusual. you should provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data that we can run to verify (it doesn't have to be your actual data). Seems like there might a typo somewhere else.

Comment: @MrFlick - ok, thank you, I'll work on providing that example

Comment: According to [t.test](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/t.test.html) documentation, when `paired=TRUE` `x` and `y` must have the same length. It seems that your isolated test failed and `ttest` was just showing an old value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You initialize the `mydf` data.frame with the values 1:4 here

```
mydf <- data.frame(c(1:4))
```

basically the loop does nothing because `t.test` is throwing an error when you do `PAIRED=TRUE` because your two sets of values aren't the same length (and they need to be when doing a paired t-test. You have 22 values where Pre==1 and 13 values where Pre==2. You can't do a paired test with an imbalance like that.

Comment: I know even less about stats than I do about coding - thank you!